# Measure that cannot be induced by a pre-measure

Tags: measure-theory

I was wondering if there are measures that cannot be constructed (induce by) from a premeasure. Since we are shrinking the algebra to sigma-algebra, some measures like those should be out there. Could any body help me to see it clear?

Comment: Note that a measure is also a premeasure and a $\sigma$-algebra is also a Boolean algebra.

Comment: Probably "premeasure" is a term specific to your textbook.  So tell us what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are using the usual definition of premeasure: Premeasure is a set function $\mu_0$ defined on a ring (or algebra) $R$ which satisfies the conditions:

- $\mu_0(\emptyset)=0$
- For every at most countable family {A_n}_n of pairwise disjoint sets in $R$, $$ \mu_0 \left(\sum_n A_n \right)=\sum_n\mu_0(A_n) $$

Answering your question:

1. Since any $\sigma$-algebra is also an algebra and any measure is also a premeasure, then any measure $\mu$ is induced by $\mu$ itself, considered as a premeasure.
2. If you ask if there is a measure $\mu$ that can not be induced by a premeasure other than $\mu$ itself. The answer is YES. Here is a simple example:

Consider $X=\{a, b, c, d\}$, the $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma=\{\emptyset, \{a,b\}, \{c,d\}, X\}$ and $\mu$ the counting measure defined on $\Sigma$. The only ring or algebra $R$ that is a proper subset of $\Sigma$ is $R=\{\emptyset, X\}$ (which is also a $\sigma$-algebra). Any premeasure $\mu_0$ defined in $R$ will not induced any measure beyond $R$, so it can not induce $\mu$. So $\mu$ can not be induced by a premeasure other than $\mu$ itself.

Comment: Hi, Ramiro, let me express the greatest appreciation for your answer: it made me see this topic much clearer.

Comment: @Jane You are welcome.  May I suggest then that you "accept" the answer?  http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer .